# Get users sanctum token in laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, sanctum

I am developing restfull API using laravel with sanctum authentication. and I also created a user dashboard to see all api consumption activities. My question is, how do I get a token from a logged in user?

[image]

Comment: With sanctum authentication, you can try ```$user->currentAccessToken();``` to get user access token

Comment: Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication,

You can create multiple tokens if needed and purge them when required. Its also possible to define the abilities, which in your case might be accessing a specific endpoint only.

Comment: hi @PaulJ.K, thanks for comment, but i can't get my user token, my code $user->currentAccessToken()->token and returns 29b0841c6e082b2eb15163bfc7a7b828e81312d71dde0c860cc7e7396d3c3381 and its hashed...

Comment: It's a token, it will be hashed, you can use plainTextToken only when the token was created, but since laravel does not store it, you cant retrieve it afterwards. If that's the case you have to create a new one, the old one will still work unless you revoke it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Retrieve the user's Sanctum token using auth()
$user = auth()->user();
$userToken = $user->tokens->first()->token;
```

```
// Retrieve the Bearer token from the request
$bearerToken = request()->bearerToken();
```

```
// Create a new Sanctum token for the user and get the plain text token
$user = Auth::user();
$newToken = $user->createToken('MyApp')->plainTextToken;
```